# Lombok Private Constructor

Tags: java, lombok

Is there any annotation available for Lombok private NoArgConstructor? Lombok `@NoArgConstructor` creates a public Constructor with no parameter. But I want private constructor annotation.

Comment: What about if I want to create a singleton class?

Comment: @emon The usual current practice is to use an enum.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- thanks.

Comment: In the case when you have only static methods you can use the experimental [@UtilityClass](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass). "By marking your class with @UtilityClass, lombok will automatically generate a private constructor...".

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use the [access level](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/NoArgsConstructor.html) element in the annotation. `@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)`

Comment: Funny because that has more characters than actually typing the private constructor

Comment: @GabrielBB Depends on the class name right? And also it takes more lines of code if you have a style checker that enforces that braces are in separate lines.

Comment: I agree, but typing all the getters, setters and constructors is way longer than the annotation. But if you use `lombok` in one place (where it shortens the syntax), typing the private no args constructor makes your code non-consistent.